# Converting avro to parquet (using hive maybe?)

Tags: mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, avro, parquet

I'm trying to convert a bunch of multi-part avro files stored on HDFS (100s of GBs) to parquet files (preserving all data)

Hive can read the avro files as an external table using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE as_avro 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED as INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' 
LOCATION '<location>' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='<schema.avsc>');
```

But when I try to create a parquet table:

```
create external table as_parquet like as_avro stored as parquet location 'hdfs:///xyz.parquet'
```

it throws an error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown field type: uniontype<...>

Is it possible to convert uniontype to something that is a valid datatype for the external parquet table?

I'm open to alternative, simpler methods as well. MR? Pig?

Looking for a way that's fast, simple and has minimal dependencies to bother about.

Thanks

Comment: Check whether the union is a real union or just a union of `null` and a single real type. The latter simply indicates an optional value and you can represent the same type in Parquet using the `optional` keyword instead of a union.

Comment: @Zoltan It's a real union but even if I were able to, say, select a few fields from within it using hive and then write to Parquet that would also be okay. Lateral view explode() also fails on the array field which contains the union type.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting this:

```
create external table as_parquet like as_avro stored as parquet location 'hdfs:///xyz.parquet'
```

into 2 steps:

1. `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE as_parquet (col1 col1_type, ... , coln coln_type) STORED AS parquet LOCATION 'hdfs:///xyz.parquet';`
2. `INSERT INTO TABLE as_parquet SELECT * FROM as_avro;`

Or, if you have partitions, which I guess you have for this amount of data:

`INSERT INTO TABLE as_parquet  PARTITION (year=2016, month=07, day=13) SELECT <all_columns_except_partition_cols> FROM as_avro WHERE year='2016' and month='07' and day='13';`

Note:
For step 1, in order to save any typos or small mistakes in columns types and such, you can:

- Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE as_avro` and copy the create statement of as_avro table
- Replace the table name, file format and location of the table
- Run the new create statement.

This works for me...

Comment: The create external table query fails: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10043]: Either list of columns or a custom serializer should be specified. I tried adding 'like as_avro' and it throws up this error: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown field type: uniontype<..>

Comment: It's still throwing errors: FAILED: ParseException line 29:1018 cannot recognize input near 'void' ',' 'struct' in column type

Comment: Did you try my tip of copying the existing table create statement and just changing the name, file format and location?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did

Comment: If you can post the create statement u r running and I will check it

Comment: Sorry, but I can't.